# Remove hover from all elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I remove hover from all the elements using CSS or Javascript? I want to remove it on mobile but to have it on desktop. I tried using `pointer-events: none` but it's removing all the events and I want the click event to remain.

Is there a way to remove only the hover property?

Comment: What's your use case for this request?

Comment: I have some tooltips that appear on hover so I want to get rid of them on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can target all elements and their hover state using css:

```
*:hover {
  
}
```

Removing hover from mobile seems pointless since users cant really hover over elements. If they click on an element it kind of acts like a hover and having a special color for hover is therefore good, because user can see he actually cliked the element.